# Django class based views, import inside get_queryset

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm developing a small app, and I'm using class based views. I was having an issue when implementing a very simple demonstrative search functionality, having the following error:

```
Exception Type:     AttributeError 
Exception Value:    type object'MyModel' has no attribute 'objects'
```

I fixed this by including an import inside the **get_queryset**, although I had the import on the top of the file. Find below a demonstrative piece of code:

```
from mymodels.models import MyModel

class Search(generic.ListView):
    """Very simple search functionality."""
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'object_list'
    paginate_by = 5     

    def get_queryset(self):
        from mymodels.models import MyModel
        query = self.request.GET['search_text']

        return MyModel.objects.filter(title__contains = query)
```

Does anyone know why this happens this way? When I first did the  Django tutorial using class based views, I didn't have this problem.

Comment: Sounds like a circular import. Are you importing anything from your views file in your models file?

Comment: No. The only import I have in the models file is:

from django.db import models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that you reassign the name `MyModel` somewhere else in that file: you probably have `MyModel = 'whatever'` somewhere.